# arduino weather shield with gps

Tags: gps, tinygps

I have Arduino Mega and Weather shield and GPS Receiver - GP-635T (50 Channel).

here is my code for GPS

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS++.h>

TinyGPSPlus gps;

static const int RXPin = 5, TXPin = 4;
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

const byte GPS_PWRCTL = 6;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ss.begin(9600);

  pinMode(GPS_PWRCTL, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(GPS_PWRCTL, HIGH);
}

void loop()
{
  smartdelay(800);
}
```

And print weather with this code

```
void printWeather()
{
  Serial.print("lat=");
  Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6);
  Serial.print("lat=");
  Serial.print(gps.location.lng(), 6);
  Serial.print("altitude=");
  Serial.print(gps.altitude.meters());
  Serial.print("sats=");
  Serial.print(gps.satellites.value());

  char sz[32];
  Serial.print("date=");
  sprintf(sz, "%02d/%02d/%02d", gps.date.month(), gps.date.day(),gps.date.year());
  Serial.print(sz);

  Serial.print("time=");
  sprintf(sz, "%02d:%02d:%02d", gps.time.hour(), gps.time.minute(), gps.time.second());
  Serial.print(sz);
}
```

But I see only zero for location and date and time. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Until you have the correct baud rate *and* good satellite reception, many fields will be zero or empty.  I wrote a diagnostic program for [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS) that will try different baud rates and confirm that the GPS device is functioning.  The example program is in this directory:

```
examples/NMEAdiagnostic
```

Installation instructions are [here](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS/blob/master/doc/Installing.md).

If you're inside, you may not be able to receive anything.  Move next to a window or go outside.

Answer (score 0):

You need to feed the output from the GPS module to the `TinyGPSPlus` routines, otherwise they won't do anything (other than return `0`). Try adding:

```
while (Serial.available() > 0) {
  gps.encode(Serial.read());
}
```

to your `loop`. `TinyGPSPlus` comes with examples that you should have a look at. It also provides many debug statistics, e.g. the number of characters processed (`gps.charsProcessed()`) and the if these made sense (`gps.passedChecksum()`).

Comment: When I try examples in TinyGPSPlus i see     È†ÔÂ`1h±PÁ   like this symbol.

Comment: That looks like you have a mismatch in the rate settings. 9600 baud is usually the default for GPS devices. Make sure the setting on your computer is correct, too (i.e. also 9600 baud, following your code snippet).

Comment: BTW, `smartDelay` feeds the `TinyGPS` routines.  There are many issues with these libraries that I have documented and fixed in [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS).  Be sure to check out the Troubleshooting section.